# How can I use subdomain for AKS FQDN

Tags: azure, fqdn, azure-aks

for example , now I have FQDN for AKS like this : `xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com`
but I would like to create a subdomain something like `aaa.xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com` and `bbb.xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com`

I've tried to find so much but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FQDN for AKS `southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com` is managed directly by Azure.
Azure allows you to create only one more subdomain level of `southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com`, like `xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com`

You may just link your own domain to AKS FQDN, for example:

```
site1.example.com CNAME xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com

site2.example.com CNAME xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com
```

If you need to make an access to different services in AKS using different URLs, you should create Ingress and use routes, example:

```
xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com\api
xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com\web
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You make me understand clearly.